INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS query very slow
I am using BigQuery to access Google Analytics 4 data. I need to have a list of all days available and I need the number of records for each day.
I know that PARTITIONS query is still preview but I decided to use it anyways because it provides exactly what I need.
So here's the query:
SELECT table_name AS table, total_rows AS total FROM `XXX.analytics_XXX.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_name,r'^events_') ORDER BY table_name DESC LIMIT 10

The issue is that this code takes 30+ seconds to execute and this is simply unacceptable for my use case. Can anyone please point me into the right direction to have this query speed up?

If I remove the ORDER BY clause it is very fast. But why? I would like to have the ORDER BY as well.
